# Where Is My Deposit?

Tags: bitcoin-atm

I deposited 300.00 into a bitcoin ATM. 222.00 showed up in my wallet. I sent what was in my wallet to DreamMarket. This transaction has been pending for 4 days. I entered both addresses into BlockChain.....nothing very helpful came from it. Please help.

Comment: Can you post the tx id or bitcoin public address you received from the ATM? That info may help someone figure out where your btc are

Comment: It went through! My deposit showed up.